# Табличный редактор

Tags: c++

Нужно создать простенький табличный редактор 3х4. В каждой ячейке может находиться число, символ, формула (A1+B1*C1/5). Желательно средствами ООП. Кто может подсказать идею или же дать ссылку на исходники? Буду очень благодарен. Времени мало, а разобраться охота.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Идея простая. Берете C++ Builder или Visual Studio. Быстренько пишете минимальное оконное приложение. Далее на форму закидываете компонент Grid (может называться по-разному). А далее пишете обработчики событий, загрузку-сохранение, если они необходимы и пр. Дешево и сердито. Качественно? Не факт. Как уж сделаете.